# print and return another value in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a Clojure beginner question about why the following code doesn't work :

```
(defn aFun [n]
  (if (< -10 n 10) 
       ((println "Single digit" n) "A return value")
       ((println "More digits" n) "Another return value")))
```

I get a `NullPointerException` at runtime. Why ?

This function works :

```
(defn aFun [n]
  (if (< -10 n 10) 
       "A return value"
       "Another return value"))
```

And this one too :

```
(defn aFun [n]
  (if (< -10 n 10) 
       (println "Single digit" n)
       (println "More digits" n)))
```

I'd like to do both at the same time however : (compute and) return a value, while printing some things first. I'm sure this is pretty basic (not even sure how to title my question), but I can't get what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
((println "Single digit" n) "A return value")
```

... attempts to apply `(println "Single digit" n)`, which returns `nil`, as a function, to `"A return value"`.

You probably intend

```
(do (println "Single digit" n) "A return value")
```

Try, where you can, to separate side-effects from pure functional computation. Here, for example,

```
(defn single-digit? [n]
  (< -10 n +10))
```

... is pure. You can wrap it in stuff that prints what you like.

Comment: Thanks for answering my stupid question so clearly, and with additionnal details. Printing here was only for debugging purposes (is that okay in this cas?)

Comment: @nha Yes, when you are debugging it's fine to use `println`, `prn` and such for side effects.

Comment: this is such a horrible answer, straight from the java land, is clojure not beautiful enough so that there would be one function that simply prints value to stdout and returns it for easy wrap anywhere in the code?